# $n=\text{ord}(g)\Rightarrow g^n=1$

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and a $g\in G$. Then we say, that $g$ has order $n$, if $$|\langle g\rangle|=n.$$

If so, since $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup, we have $1,g\in G$. How can I now prove that $$g^n=1?$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is $0<p<n$ such that $g^p=1$ then the elements $g,g^2,\ldots,g^p=1$ are differents (why?) and for $k\ge p+1$ and using the euclidean division of $k$ by $p$ we see that $g^k$ is one of the previous elements so $\langle g\rangle=\{g,g^2,\ldots,g^p\}$ which is a contradiction since $p\ne n$.

Comment: Assume by contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Prove first that if $i$ is a positive integer   such that $g^i=1$, then for any $k\in\mathbf N$,
 $$g^k=g^{k\bmod i}.$$
If $m$ is the smallest such integer, conclude there exists a bijection from $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$ onto the subgroup $\;\langle\, g\,\rangle$.